# How much memory is a specific user account using?

Tags: memory, user-account, fast-user-switching

I have an M1 MacBook Pro, and I've just enabled fast user switching to allow my partner to use my device with her own account when I'm not using it, as we can't justify the cost of purchasing a second device for the occasional use she will need it for.

I'm a Software Developer, and my MacBook only has 16 GB of memory, so I'm quite concerned about the device being left logged on (with countless browser tabs open) consuming a good chunk of the system memory that I'd quite like to have released when she's not using the MacBook.

I'm going to set the device to automatically sign out a user after a period of inactivity so it's not really a problem, but I'm just interested to know if there is a good way of finding out how much extra memory is consumed by a second user being signed in at the same time.

I decided to put this to the test, so I've created an account for her and logged on, and I'm trying to find a fairly accurate measure of how much memory the processes linked with her active account are using. I've had a look in Activity Monitor, and I can easily see all the processes running for her account, and whilst it's easy to see individual amounts of memory in use for each process, it's difficult to get a good estimate of the total memory used by her account overall. I know I can look at the total memory usage and compare the figures of two accounts signed in, versus just one, but I was hoping for something a little more 'scientific' than that.

I can list all of the processes running with her account easily with `ps -u username`, but that doesn't output the memory usage for each process (or give a summary).

Is there a clean method of determining this?

Comment: You don't generally need to worry about this. MacOS uses virtual memory, automatically moving memory between disk and RAM as necessary. Memory of idle processes is automatically moved to disk when active processes need the memory.